# Using multiple instances of a specific UserControl within an application to reference itself

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, tabcontrol

I got this class in Visual Basic:

```
class Dumbo
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    Me.DataSet = New DataSet
    Me.BS = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource

Sub New()
    Me.BS.DataMember = "Table1"
    Me.DataSource = Me.DataSet
End Sub 

    'Other commands here for doing interactions with a SQL database

End Class
```

Using a tabcontrol on the Main Window, I have this user control working fine on the first tabpage so that operator can enter in data, or view previous records in the database, but now I need to add this to another panel on another tab control

So just doing this:

```
dim Dumbo1 = new Dumbo      'Usercontrol on the first tab
dim Dumbo2 = new Dumbo      'Usercontrol on the second tab
```

I know that simply writing Dumbo2 = Dumbo1 doesn't work at all. I could try and set the Dataset and the Bindingsource to each other, but isn't there a simpler way of just referencing to the class instead?

**EDIT**: I'm drawing from an experience in C++ where you use the address of a class (&foo) if you wanted to reference the same class.

so if you have this:

```
ClassFoo foo = new ClassFoo();
ClassFoo *foo1 = &foo;
```

Therefore I can use the same class fields, properties, and methods to read/write to the database. The data has to be the same datarow ON BOTH TABPAGES

I was hoping there was a cheap and dirty trick in VB.NET where I can reference the same Usercontrol, so when the user switches tabpages, it will be the same data, like be able to read the same data, and/or write and then commit the changes and it would reflect the modifications on the other page. Or similar to the ByRef (or Ref in C#) to reference THAT class ONLY.

I hope that clears it up a bit. :-)

Comment: The subject of your question does not match its body. If you write Dumbo1 = Dumbo2 Dumbo1 points to the same memory location of Dumbo2 (two different references to the same memory location). Perhaps you would like a copy constuctor?

Comment: If it is a UserControl why not drag a new one from the toolbox to whereever you want it.  `dim Dumbo1 = new Dumbo ` is not "referencing the class"  but creating an *instance* of the class.  The class is a type, whereas `Dumbo1` is an `Object`.  Since Dumbo2 is a different object on a different tab on a different panel you probably want a different object...hard to tell what you are really asking

Comment: I think you mean "just referencing the <i>instance of</i> the class, instead," right?

Comment: Yes--it seems that you want the same object on both tabs--is there any reason you can't just reference Dumbo1 on the second tab?

Comment: Or if you're looking to somehow create a copy of an object, instead of declaring Dumbo2 = new Dumbo, just declare it like this `dim dumbo2 as Dumbo = Dumbo1`  As others have said, your question's wording is a little hard to understand what you're looking for.  Hard to tell if you're looking for 2 copies of the same object (as I've supplied) or a copy constructor as sblandin suggested, or if you're simply after being able to access the same object across multiple tabs..

Comment: You could simply **move** the UserControl to the current Tab whenever a new tab is selected.  Adding the control to the new tab would remove it from the existing one automatically.

Comment: But in VB.NET foo and foo1 ARE references, you just don't need a special syntax

Comment: Showing the same data on two tabs only requires the same datasource. 2 different controls could use the same DataSource without any gyrations

Answer (score 0):

Your tabcontrol control could contain your New Dumbo variable. Each tab would reference that variable from the tabcontrol.

Inside a TabPage, you would have

```
CType(Me.Parent, CustomTabControl).Dumbo
```

An other option is when the TabControl initialize each tab, it would send out the variable.

In the TabControl you would have

```
someName = New Dumbo

For Each tab As TabPage In Me.TabPages
    tab.Tag = someName
Next
```